# Disable auto-opening nautilus window after auto-mount

Tags: nautilus, mount, usb-drive, external-hdd, automount

Every time I plug a USB stick in, nautilus opens a new window with the contents of the drive. I would like to disable this auto-opening of the nautilus window, but I would like the actual auto-mount to keep working. Is this possible?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Turns out, it is. You will need `dconf-editor` tool, which can be installed by with `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`. Run `dconf-editor` in your terminal. Browse to org -> gnome -> desktop - media-handling. Uncheck `automount-open`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.10, you just need to install "dconf Editor" (dconf-editor).  Run it once it's been added to your Launcher.  Then do the same thing.

Answer (score 303):

The simplest option is to open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: How shall I know which settings can be changed using *gsettings set* ? can you provide any documentation or list ?

Comment: This doesn't work in Gnome-Shell. It still pops-up that notification asking to "Open with Files" or "Eject" or "Open with music player", etc.

Comment: This didn't work for me on 15.04 with Unity.  The graphical `dconf` solution did.

Comment: Confirmed on 16.04. For an Android developer, this is really a relief!

Comment: Didn't work on an earlier Ubuntu for me (15.10 or 16.04 probably) but did now work on 16.10.

Comment: If run this command via `sudo`, it may not work, Why?

Comment: Worked on 16.04 perfectly, Thanks man, @StephanHenningsen really :D

Comment: On Linux Mint this was `gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.media-handling automount-open false` for me. So `cinnamon` instead of `gnome`. Presumably this would have to changed also if you use Mate instead. Etc etc ...

Comment: List all data from `gsettings` with descriptions: `gsettings list-recursively | while read path name value; do echo "$path.$name=$value"; gsettings describe "$path" "$name"; echo; done`

Answer (score 21):

The setting corresponding to izx's to disable automatically launching `nemo` in the `cinnamon` desktop is:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
```

Answer (score 1):

For **MATE Desktop Environment**, which uses the **Caja** file manager:

```
gsettings set org.mate.media-handling automount-open false
```

or use Caja File Management Preferences (`caja-file-management-properties`) - on Media tab uncheck *Browse media when inserted* checkbox.

Not for Gnome or Cinnamon desktop environments, however MATE/Caja is a close relative.

Answer (score -1):

Using GUI in debian gnome desktop:

Open `dconf-editor` then go to `org -> gnome -> desktop - media-handling`.
There uncheck automount.

Comment: This will disable auto-mounting altogether. OP only wants do disable the pop-up windows after auto-mount. -1

Comment: yes, it disables the auto-mounting also. my answer is only for disabling pop-up window.

Comment: No, it's not. Please read the description of the Dconf key `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.automount` (“If set to true, then Nautilus will automatically mount media such as user-visible hard disks and removable media on start-up and media insertion.”) as opposed to `.automount-open` (“If set to true, then Nautilus will automatically open a folder when media is automounted.”).