# Nautilus Opens Devices on Every Log in

Tags: nautilus, login, 12.10, devices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable auto-opening nautilus window after auto-mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191527/disable-auto-opening-nautilus-window-after-auto-mount)

Each and every time I log in to Ubuntu 12.10 Nautilus opens and opens my two mounted hard drives in devices, one after the other, in separate Nautilus windows. This wouldn't be too much of a problem, however Nautilus seems very unstable in 12.10 and frequently hangs anyway when browsing files. So when this happens I see my Desktop for about 1-2 seconds and then before I have chance to do anything, it opens the first device in the File Manager, hangs, then the second, hangs, and then I am waiting an extra 30s before I can actually use my desktop. Fortunately I just have the two devices set to auto mount on boot.

How do I stop Ubuntu from opening these devices every login? No other version did this, from 12.04 backwards.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Fixed it, although there doesn't seem to be a way to do this via Ubuntu itself. I had to use Ubuntu Tweak and set it not to open folder automatically under Tweaks > File Manager. Of course this now means that when I insert a removable drive I have to open Nautilus manually, shame it is either or, but that seems to be the way of it with 12.10.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/191527/disable-auto-opening-nautilus-window-after-auto-mount Using this, you can keep automounting but not pop up windows for all mounted drives.