# Don't show mounted folders on start

Tags: mount, automount, cifs

Ubuntu opens a Nautilus for every mounted Windows share right after login. How can I suppress this?
It's Ubuntu 12.10 and filesystem is cifs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ubuntu Tweak, under Tweaks > File Manager, set "Automatically open a folder" to off.

This answer came from...
[Nautilus Opens Devices on Every Log in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203770/nautilus-opens-devices-on-every-log-in)

---

How to get Ubuntu Tweak. In Terminal...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

This came from...
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/ubuntu-tweak-gets-full-ubuntu-1210.html

---

I was having this problem with opening TrueCrypt volumes and thought it was a bug involving TrueCrypt.  I now believe it is a designed feature of Ubuntu.