# How do I gvfs-mount without opening a file manager window?

Tags: bash, mount, automount, autostart, gvfs

I like to have my `devices` **mounted** in Nautilus/Nemo **by default** when I log in, so I can have `symlinks` to certain directories.

And I don't mean a custom mount or a mount with 10 lines of `cryptSetup` and `luksOpen` commands that would require me to hardcode a `LUKS` password. Not only because, but also because it is not compatible with the `devices` list in Nautilus/Nemo.

[image]

To do this, I can have an autostart script (`Startup Applications`) using `gvfs-mount -d` like so, very easy to maintain and it will automatically get LUKS-passwords from the keyring if necessary:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Redsandro 2013-03-01
# Mount (LUKS) drives and such

doMount() {
    # Devices change every now and then. UUID does not.
    DEV=`ls -l --color=never /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep $UUID | cut -d\>  -f2 | cut -d/ -f3`
    gvfs-mount -d /dev/$DEV
}

# LUKS-1TB
# /dev/sdb1
UUID='9dd6df52-c901-4b70-8151-27086ba7db16'
doMount

# Projects 1TB
# /dev/sdd1
UUID='6b01a30e-af6e-48b4-810a-f9824558f041'
doMount

# MyBook 1
# /dev/sdc2
UUID='b36a4a52-a73d-43b5-a96a-d92074b8ef3f'
doMount

# MyBook 2
# /dev/sdc3
UUID='c771609f-018e-45a4-b4f3-5eebc8e67c83'
doMount
```

However, this will open a window for every device. How can I prevent those windows from opening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [here (in another question)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191527/disable-auto-opening-nautilus-window-after-auto-mount) for `Nautilus`:

- **In GUI**
  Install and/or run `dconf-editor`. Browse to *org -> gnome -> desktop - media-handling*.
  Uncheck `automount-open`.
- **In Terminal**

  `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false`

There should be a similar option for `Nemo` since it is a fork of `Nautilus`.

**Note** that this will prevent `Nautilus` to open windows for **any** new mounted device (including USB keys).

There is no simple mean I'm aware of to selectively open windows for some devices and not for others (eg. there *are* means, but not simple; they require scripting and technical knowledge).

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest answer so far. I've edited your answer (pending peer review) to incorporate the two linked solutions, and accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong! You need to edit `/etc/fstab`. this is a sample :

```
/dev/sda1   /   ext2    defaults    1 1
/dev/sda2   /home/mostafa/musics    ext2    defaults    1 2
```

In the above, device `/dev/sda2` is mounted to `/home/mostafa/Musics`

Comment: No, using `fstab` for this purpose is wrong. First, hotpluggable drives will cause mount-errors. Second, personal drives do not need to be hard-coded on a global scale (root in stead of user). Third, I would need to hard-code LUKS passwords. Fourth, this will remove the mounted hardware from the handy `devices` list. Sixth, gvfs-mount was developed specifically for this purpose.