# How do I prevent automatic mounting of my android phone in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, android, automount, gvfs

gvfs is mounting my phone automatically when I plug it in, I don't want this for various reasons.

How do I disable automatic mounting for this specific device, but continue allowing other USB devices to automount?

Here's the mount after plugging in :

```
~$ gvfs-mount -l
Drive(0): ST320LT007-9ZV142
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Drive(1): HL-DT-ST DVD+/-RW GU60N
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Drive(2): Generic Ultra HS-SD/MMC
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Volume(0): Galaxy Nexus
  Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorMTP)
  Mount(0): Galaxy Nexus -> mtp://[usb:002,020]/
    Type: GProxyShadowMount (GProxyVolumeMonitorMTP)
Mount(0): mtp -> mtp://[usb:002,020]/
  Type: GDaemonMount
```

**Update Tue May 21 00:03:00 EDT 2013:**

I found /usr/share/gvfs/mounts/mtp.mount which contains:

```
[Mount]
Type=mtp
Exec=/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp
AutoMount=false
```

Unhappily this AutoMount parameter doesn't seem to do anything.

In the meantime I've followed advice from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191527/disable-auto-opening-nautilus-window-after-auto-mount) and disabled automount-open and automount in the gconf settings under `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling`.  This disables it globally but it's better than the alternative.  Here's hoping we'll have device- or protocol-specific (or both!) gvfs automount configuration in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure you can sorry...

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-my-all-of-my-drives-automatically/271527#271527) and see if it helps.

Comment: @Mitch thanks, but gnome-disks doesn't manage gvfs mounts, that's for stuff in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Opened a bug here https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790488 let's see what the developers think about that.