# Can not Unmount mtp

Tags: mount, android, mtp

Events in chronological order:

- 2 days before I connected my friend's phone (Motorola G2) via data cable but somehow it does not mount properly and so I have to unmount it
- It unmounted properly but a strange named **mtp** mount itself automatically which can't be opened.
- I trying unmounting it but it does not unmount, returning a error and there is no folder named **mtp** in `/media` which can be deleted to unmount it.
- After rebooting the system there was no problem encountered the drive named mtp does not appear again.
- Today I transferred some data from mobile(Honor 4x) via data cable,there was no problem transferring data but when I unmounted the Android drive this **mtp** drive starts showing again and again same problem starts.

Now what is this mtp and how can it be unmounted safely so that It does not appear again and why is it mounting itself again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect your android Phone to computer you can select the connection "mode". Modes are "Only charging", MTP, PTP. Older Android devices supported also the mode where the device was connected as "USB Mass Storage". MTP means "Media Transfer Protocol" and when used the Phone appears to computer as Media Device. It is used for transfering audio/video files. PTP means "Picture Transfer Protocol". When used the Phone appears to computer as digital camera and software that supports grabbing photos from a digital camera will support grabbing photos from an Android phone when you select the PTP mode.

[Reference.](http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/)

The "USB Mass Storge" mode was removed in modern devices. This caused me a lot of problems when I was trying to recover deleted photos from my phone. The `TestDisk` software did not detect the phones internal storage.

To prevent Nautilus (File Manager) from opening a window after connecting your phone look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191527/disable-auto-opening-nautilus-window-after-auto-mount) answer.

To prevent automounting your phone when connected try [this](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/07/quick-tips-easy-way-to-disable-auto-mount-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts.html) link.

Comment: Ok I select mtp mode to transfer data but how can I unmount mtp that is showing side pane

Comment: I can click the unmount symbol next to Android Phone line in file manager and it unmounts. Than when I disconnect the cable the icon also disapears.

Comment: I think you did not read the question carefully the problem is I can not unmount a drive named mtp ,I can easily unmount my Android phone. Please read question one more time.