# VeraCrypt text mode only

Tags: veracrypt

I have a script where it mounts a veracrypt container for me, RSYNC files in this container and then dismount it.

The problem is that everytime I run it, when it mounts the container, it opens the Nautilus/Files Window and I do not want to trigger any Window in this proccess, I want it to be text only in CLI.

Here is a test script as example:

```
# Dismount all existing containers
veracrypt -d

# Mount container
veracrypt -t --mount ~/Downloads/vault /media/veracrypt -p test --non-interactive

# Sync files
rsync -varz --delete ~/Downloads/test.txt /media/veracrypt/

# Dismount
veracrypt -d
```

Even putting `-t` and `--non-interactive` it stills open the Files window. Does anyone have a clue how to avoid that?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure but I think opening a Nautilus window is the default behavior for any new "drive" connected to the system, like what happens when you connect a USB stick. Mounting a new (virtual) drive with Veracrypt it's the same. So, I think there's no way to prevent that from Veracrypt regardless of options because Veracrypt cannot control what the OS does by default. Preventing Nautilus from opening new windows is then the way to go. How to do that I don't know.

Comment: You can try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/191527/disable-auto-opening-nautilus-window-after-auto-mount

Comment: @MichaelBay yeah I thought of it at night when I arrived at home, it's not veracrypt's fault, it's the OS default behavior ... Could you transfer your comment to a separated answer so I can mark it as resolved? :-)